# Test for PHP Errors using Browser Emulator (Mink)

Tags: php, error-handling, acceptance-testing, end-to-end

**I want to know the most robust way of checking for PHP error messages when running automated tests that interact with a PHP application via a browser emulator.**

The reason is: I use Behat, Mink and Selenium/Webkit/etc to test my PHP applications in the following ways:

- as acceptance tests, to make sure expected functionality exists
- as end-to-end tests, to test success of complete integration

And so it seems obvious to me that most tests run by Behat/Mink should additionally parse the pages they do tests on for PHP errors, warnings, notices etc, as a matter of course.

But, it's not easy, for a number of reasons:

1. The server that the PHP application is running on may output errors differently, depending on factors such as whether XDebug is used.
2. On a production server, errors, warnings and so on would not be output at all.

AFAIK, nothing can be done about point 2? So if I wanted my behat test results regarding parsing for PHP errors to be meaningful, it would have to be done on a server where the configuration is to display errors.

But regarding point 1, **I have a simple idea for how to achieve it**: explicitly use error and exception handlers within the PHP application so if/when they are output, they will be in a format that can be easily parsed and tested for.

It seems like a reasonable idea, yet has a bad smell about it. **So I would like to know if**:

1. **There is another way of more robustly looking for errors in end-to-end tests**
2. **I am going about this whole thing in the wrong way.**

Comment: I usually configure the PHP server not to output error/warning messages, but to log them. You don't need to create your own error handling for this because it is a built-in option.

Comment: So I should have the Behat tests delve into the server's logs each time it wants to check if a page had errors? It would really make the tests run slowly if the server's not on localhost

Comment: Not the server logs. Use a specific log file for your application, then your test script can just look at that file. Look here for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file